# Recode when a part of certain text is included in R

Tags: r, recode

I need to recode a variable when it has a certain text. Here is a sample dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 var1 = c("Discontinue", "Discontunie","discontinue", "disc","DISCONTINUE","NR"))

> df
  id        var1
1  1 Discontinue
2  2 Discontunie
3  3 discontinue
4  4        disc
5  5 DISCONTINUE
6  6          NR
```

`var1` has discontinue information with some typos, upper, lower cases etc. I believe using `disc` text would be a good catch to identify those values. I need to recode the `v1` as `discontinue`. How can I get the following manipulation.

```
   > df
      id        var1
    1  1 discontinue
    2  2 discontinue
    3  3 discontinue
    4  4 discontinue
    5  5 discontinue
    6  6          NR
```

Comment: It is not clear how many other cases should be classified into `discontinue` as `disc` is just 4 characters prefix

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 var1 = c("Discontinue", "Discontunie","discontinue", "disc","DISCONTINUE","NR"))


df$var1 <- ifelse(grepl("^disc", df$var1, ignore.case = TRUE), "discontinue", df$var1)
df
#>   id        var1
#> 1  1 discontinue
#> 2  2 discontinue
#> 3  3 discontinue
#> 4  4 discontinue
#> 5  5 discontinue
#> 6  6          NR
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick, which identifies the rows where `var1` contains text `disc` using `grep`, regardless of case (`ignore.case = TRUE`), and replaces it with "discontinue":

```
df[grep("disc", df$var1, ignore.case = TRUE), "var1"] <- "discontinue"
```

Output:

```
#   id        var1
# 1  1 discontinue
# 2  2 discontinue
# 3  3 discontinue
# 4  4 discontinue
# 5  5 discontinue
# 6  6          NR
```